# How to do has_many and has_one association in same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I need to do two associations in the same model. Where:

**Team** `has_many` **User**
Now, I want that **Team** `has_one` **Leader**

This "Leader" will be a User

Im trying to use `has_one throught` but I think that association isn't work.

Leader.rb

```
class Leader < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :team
```

Team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :user, through: :leader
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :team
has_one :captain

end
```

and the get following error around line 27:

```
NoMethodError in TeamsController#create

26 def create

**27 @team = current_user.teams.create(team_params)**

28 @team.save

29 respond_with(@team)

30 current_user.update(team_id: @team.id)
```

Comment: Can a user be in more teams, or only one team?

Comment: because `current_user` is a user, not a leader/captain, for your method to work you need `current_user.(leader/captain).teams.create(team_params)`, also check your assocciations, is it leader or is it captain

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In this case I think you need 2 model are enough

1). User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :team
end
```

2). Team model

```
 class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
   belongs_to :leader, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :leader_id
 end
```

Comment: with this I dont need the table "leaders" ?

Comment: exactly , you don't need leaders table anymore.

Comment: @LuanD, Thanks for the great answer, but where leader_id  key belongs ?  in user ? I dont get that line. Can you explain me please ?

Comment: @Vishal , No leader_id key belongs Team table.

Comment: @LuanD, Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 5):

How about setting a `boolean` flag in users table called `leader`. And then your association can become:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :users   
  has_one :leader, class_name: 'User', -> { where leader: true }
end
```

Comment: But then wouldn't you theoretically be able to have multiple leaders?

Answer (score 4):

> Team has_many User Now, I want that Team has_one Leader
>
> This "Leader" will be a User

Use inheritance (also called sub-classing), Leader is a User.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
end

class Leader < User
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_one :leader
end
```

Your users table is also important. Ensure that users has `t.belongs_to :team` and `t.string :type` in its create_table method. Note that a Leader is a User and does not need a separate table, however you do need to allow ActiveRecord to record its type so it can return the correct Model later.

References:

[inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) specifically you need 'single table inheritance'

[belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) scroll down for has_one and has_many, the three relationships used here.

Comment: I think this is better as it allows more changes in the future with only one additional column (type). With the accepted answer, the `leader_id` column only works for leaders...

Answer (score 1):

`current_user.teams.create(team_params)`

Teams is for a `has_many` association, you want `current_user.create_team(team_params)`

Comment: Hello... the record doesn't save in the 'captains' table...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have `has_one` association between `user` and `team`. Try this:

```
current_user.create_team(team_params)
```

Also, you should add proper back association from `team` to `leader`.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leader
  has_one :user, through: :leader
end
```

Comment: Hello... the record doesn't save in the 'captains' table...thanks

Comment: What is `captains` table? You have not specified about this in your question. BTW, is this answer helped you to get rid of your original problem?

Comment: Sorry...captains was wrong...is Leader. I've edited my question. Isn't saving yet =(